# Migrating from Roo to Grails

Tags: grails, spring-mvc, spring-roo

I have an web application developed using Spring Roo. This is just a standard Roo application with only a few Java classes that were not generated by Roo itselef. After using Grails for a while in another application, I decided to move my application to Grails because of Groovy and its large set of plugins.

My question is: **which strategy should I use to migrate from Spring Roo to Spring Grails?** My first guess is to remove Roo from my application as described [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html/removing.html) and then install the [SpringMVC plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/springmvc) on the new Grails application so I can continue using my old application artifacts on the new project.

The first step is very simple, but the second is not clear for me yet. I have found an article about using spring controllers and jsps [here](http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=58), but I am still worried as this is an application already in production. Is there anything else I am not considering? I would appreciate any suggestions or warnings on this strategy.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The springmvc plugin was quite dated so I updated it to work with Grails 2.0+ - see http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=1735 for more information and a sample applicaiton. If you have any issues using it please report them in JIRA at http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPSPRINGMVC

Comment: Thanks a lot for writing that plugin and keeping it up to date, Burt.